# How to disable "event_type":"ContainerMetric" in PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry

After certain interval, the pcf prints out logs with memory_bytes", "memory_bytes_quota". How to disable it?

Comment: What is your concern with these?  Why do you need to turn them off?  Also, do you have a specific example of where you're seeing these?

Comment: I want to turn them off as they fill-up the log files & makes it difficult to debug issues.

Comment: Can you explain, what you mean by log files? Nothing should be written to log files. For cloud foundry, the approach is to deploy an app called `nozzle` which redirects all logs to a TSDB tool like ELK or Splunk. You can then build dashboards for your logs in Splunk or Kibana and look at your app logs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable the metrics that come from the platform.  They will be emitted for every application.  If you really don't want this information, your option would be to filter it out.

You could filter it after the fact, using your log viewing tool (ELK, Splunk, etc..).  The UI's all have ways to filter out unwanted messages.

Another option would be to filter it out before it's ingested by your logging platform.  How you do that would vary quite a bit.  Your logging platform likely gives you a way to filter unwanted logs, so you'd probably want to refer to the docs for your logging platform.

Yet another possibility is that you have a nozzle which is listening to the CF firehose, taking messages and sending them onto your logging platform (ELK, Splunk, etc..).  In this case, the nozzle would be another point where you could filter logs. Nozzles are custom software, so capabilities will vary.  Check with the docs for your nozzle to see if it offers this capability, and if so, how you'd use it.